# Diophantine Equations of degree 3 and 4

Tags: calculus, diophantine-equations

I have these two Diophantine equations: $$0 = x^2 y - 36 x^2 - 12 x y + 36 x + 36 y - 9$$ and $$0 = x^2y^2 - 36 x^2 - 12 x y^2 + 36 x + 36 y^2 - 9$$ Each of them is slightly different from each other, but the first one is of degree 3 while the one is degree 4. Can any one of them be solved without factoring and if so, how? I graphed it but nothing really stood out.

Comment: you can write the first equation like this $y=\frac{9(2x-1)^2}{(x-6)^2}$

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: This implies $y$ is the square of a rational number therefore, since $y$ is an integer, $y$ is the square of an integer. So $x-6$ must divide $6x-3$. From this conclude that $x-6$ must divide $33$. I just realized this has been done below in an answer form  by @Dr. Mathva

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that you asked for solutions without factorizing, but factorizing is the best way - if not the only one - to solve diophantine equations.

From $(1)$ we obtain $$y= \bigg(\frac{6x-3}{x-6}\bigg)^2$$

Since $y\in\mathbb Z$, so does $$\frac{6x-3}{x-6}=\frac{6\cdot (x-6)+33}{x-6}=6+\frac{33}{x-6}$$ Hence, $x-6\mid 11\cdot 3$, which implies that

$$x-6=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\pm 33\\
\pm11\\
\pm3\\
\pm1
\end{array}
\right.$$

It's easy to end it now (solve each equation separately). The second case is very similar.

Comment: How does that help me?

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake again.

Comment: Also, they are not a system of equations, but different equations.

Comment: Yes, I checked them. No more editing on my part. ;)

Comment: Oh, thanks, but are you sure there is no other way?

Comment: I would say no, but you can never say never... At least I can guarantee that this is the easiest way of solving the problem (don't you agree that, once had the idea, the problem was simple?)

Comment: Well, yes it was...

Comment: @QuoteDave Please consider upvoting or/and accepting the question if it helped you ;)

Comment: I will vote it up because its a good answer, but I won't accept it because it uses factorization.

Comment: That's fair. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your first equation can be written as $$y(x-6)^2-(x-3)^2=0$$ and the second as
$$y^2(x-6)^2-(x-3)^2=0$$

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally wrote the wrong equations

Comment: Also, how does this help me?